# Elasticsearch delete all snapshots at once

Tags: elasticsearch, repository, snapshot

Delete all Elasticsearch snapshots at once.

I have a couple of file system snapshot repositories like the following.

```
PUT /_snapshot/test
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "/mnt/nfs/test",
    "max_restore_bytes_per_sec": "1024mb",
    "compress": "true",
    "max_snapshot_bytes_per_sec": "1024mb"
  }
}
```

And I have snapshots from 2021 in that repositories. The snapshots look like the following.

- index_name-2021-02-03
- index_name-2021-02-04
- index_name-2021-02-05
- ...
- index_name-2023-05-25

The only method I can find is removing snapshots one by one with some shell script, each snapshot deletion process takes 20 minutes. the `index_name` index size of about 10TB (1 pri + 1 rep).
the Elasticsearch version is 7.7.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way to remove multiple snapshots at once? (with regex)
2. Will it be faster if I remove multiple snapshots at once like `DELETE _snapshot/repo_name/index_name-2021-02-03,index_name-2021-02-04`?
3. How can I remove all snapshots in the repository? ([removing a repository won't remove snapshots.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/delete-snapshot-repo-api.html))

Similar question. [How to delete a snapshot data in Elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60447478/how-to-delete-a-snapshot-data-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: Hey Musab, have those snapshots been taken manually or are they created via a snapshot lifecycle management policy?

Comment: Hey Val, all snapshots triggered by some shell script, the ES not eligible for to run SLM policy because they are using OSS version of elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks, though, Snapshot lifecycle management is available in the Free and Open version of ES: https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions

Comment: SLM is available on free and basic but not in OSS as far as I researched.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Elasticsearch-OSS 7.7.0

Comment: You're right, unfortunately, SLM [was not supported](https://web.archive.org/web/20200513183210/https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions) on ES-OSS 7.7.0 (released on 13.05.2020)

Comment: Even more troublesome that 7.7.0 didn't even have API endpoints for deleting snapshots, that only came in 7.8.0

Comment: Are those indexes present in snapshots also opened in your cluster or only present in snapshots?

Comment: Some of them still exist some of them not. But I don't need the old once any more

Comment: Ok, then if you close or delete the older indexes you don't need, you should be able to leverage the [`_cleanup` repository endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/snapshots-register-repository.html#snapshots-repository-cleanup) in order to delete all the unreferenced data in the snapshots, and eventually the snapshots themselves